# How can I print values inside an array made from a string? (Explode)

Tags: php

I'm not looking for a var dump, I just want the actual data inside each key of my array.

Original String: (meta_value) `1698, 4655, 4215, 1225, 5454, 698, 410, 122, 107, 7412, 3654, 1120`

```
$explodeme = $serial['meta_value'];
$exploded = explode(",",$explodeme[0]);
var_dump($exploded);
```

Returns:

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "1" } array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "9" } array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "1" } array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "9" } array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "1" } array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "1" } array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "1" } array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "1" } array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "1" } array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "1" } array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "1" } array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "1" } array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "1" } array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "1" } array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "1" } array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "1" } array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "1" } array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "1" }
```

I want to print the strings for every single key of my array. IE)

```
Serial Number: 42848 <- From Array
Serial Number: 48281 <- From Array
```

I have tried:

```
echo $exploded;
print_r($exploded);
```

All return the same value (See *Returns:* above)

I've also tried a for each loop, but it doesn't output the serial number string I have stored inside the array.

```
foreach ($exploded as $item) {
  echo $item . "<br>";
}
```

I've also tried (to no avail):

```
foreach ($exploded as $item) {
  echo $item['string(1)'] . "<br>";
}
```

Please help!

Comment: Can you edit the question to show the original string?

Comment: @Don'tPanic Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `$serial['meta_value']` holds the comma separated string, like this:

```
$serial['meta_value'] = '1698, 4655, 4215, 1225, 5454, 698, 410, 122, 107, 7412, 3654, 1120';
```

Then your error was using `$explodeme[0]` in this expression:

```
$exploded = explode(",",$explodeme[0]);
```

`$explodeme[0]` is the first character of the string. (See the PHP documentation for [String access and modification by character.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.substr)) Instead you should just use `$explodeme` to get the entire string.

```
$explodeme = $serial['meta_value'];
$exploded = explode(",", $explodeme);

foreach ($exploded as $item) {
    echo $item . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: This is EXACTLY the problem. I can't believe I didn't notice my [0]. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I've just tested this and the below seems to be working with a simple foreach loop.

```
<?php
$string = "1698, 4655, 4215, 1225, 5454, 698, 410, 122, 107, 7412, 3654, 1120";

$exploded = explode(',', $string);

foreach ($exploded as $item ) {
    echo $item;
}
?>
```